# Issue on wpdb queries, wp_insert_post. The function adds duplicate post

Tags: wordpress

Anyone encountered this issue?

I have created a custom php script which adds a new post by using `wp_insert_post()` but everytime I run the code it creates a 2 new post where in it should be only be one, its like it runs twice, so I tested another function using `wpdb->query` and its also the same its really weird. Please help I dont know what causes and how to fix this issue.

Thank you very much.

Here is a sample code i did just to test the issue and it still creates 2 identical post

```
function testtest(){
      $ads_data = array(
            'post_title'    => "test",
            'post_content'  => "test",
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'ads',
            //'post_author' => $user_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $ads_id = wp_insert_post( $ads_data );
}add_shortcode('testtest','testtest');
```

**SOLVED**

I have figured it out now, whats causing the issue is on my header.php it is this line of code:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'favicon' ) ); ?>" />
```

I find it really weird, i have no idea why that line of code is causing the issue, anyway thanks everyone!

Comment: can you post your code..so i can check

Comment: $ads_data = array(
        'post_title'    => "test",
        'post_content'  => "test",
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'ads',
        //'post_author' => $user_id
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $ads_id = wp_insert_post( $ads_data );

Comment: What hook are you running this code on? It's probably firing the hook twice.

Comment: what is `post_status` of that both post..is that both `publish`??

Comment: @MichaelMarr i just created a shortcode that runs that code, ive edited my question now.

Comment: @JivaniJaydeep yes they are both publish, the 2 post are identical

Comment: is this in functions.php, or some plugin file? are you running `add_shortcode('testtest', 'testtest')` anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Check before going to insert new post if already exists or not. So **get_page_by_title('Some Post Title') == false** then only insert new post.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_func' );

function my_func()  {
$my_post = '';
if( get_page_by_title('test','OBJECT','ads') == NULL )
$my_post= array(
        'post_title'    => 'test',
        'post_name'     => 'test',
        'post_type'     => 'ads',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
);
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```